# Снятие конфигураций с сетевых устройств по SSH c использованием perl

Tags: perl, openssh

Как с использованием SSH на языке Perl собирать конфигурацию сетевых устройств в автоматическом режима с использованием планировщика?
Причем, нужно в одной сессии вводить несколько команд.
Предлагаемые решения с использованием модулей Net::SSH, Net::SSH2 не всегда работают на современных устройствах. Работает Net::OpenSSH.
Но указанный ниже пример кода (из описания модуля), как и другие варианты, работает при подключении к linux, но при подключении к промышленному коммутатору Huawei AR550 (команда другая, конечно), приводит к зависанию скрипта и отсутствию вывода

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
my ($out, $err) = $ssh->capture2("find /root");
print $out;
```

Comment: и в чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: Извиняюсь. Но вопроса нет. Только ответ. Просто хотел поделится. Пару дней потратил на поиск решения, и вот, получилось. Хотелось оставить где-то, где сам искал. Может кому пригодится. Спасибо!

Comment: должен быть вопрос, а к нему — ответ(ы). если и вопрос и ответ пишете сами — это только [приветствуется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/178576). но оформите, пожалуйста, по правилам данного сайта: вопрос — отдельно, ответ — отдельно.

Comment: Понял. Постараюсь сделать. Спасибо!

Comment: Отредактировал. Сделал вопрос- ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Работающий код:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
use Expect;

select STDOUT; $| = 1;
select STDERR; $| = 1;

my $host = '10.1.1.1';
my $user = 'user';
my $password = 'password';
my $pre = '>'; # - знак приглашения командной строки сетевого устройства
my $timeout = 20;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($hostv, user=> $user, password => $old);

my ($pty, $pid) = $ssh->open2pty();

my $expect = Expect->init($pty);
$expect->raw_pty(1);    
$expect->expect($timeout, $pre);
$expect->send("screen 0 temp\n") ;#команда, которую нужно выполнить
$expect->expect($timeout, $pre);
print $expect->before;#вывести результат команды

$expect->send("dis curr\n") ;#другая команда, которую нужно выполнить
$expect->expect($timeout, $pre);
print $expect->before;#вывести результат команды
```